# Keep original typescript source maps after using browserify

Tags: javascript, typescript, browserify, source-maps

Background: I am compiling 2 dependent TypeScript files to js, which produces also source maps (one source map per file) using tsc 1.0

I'm using `-m commonjs` and then use browserify to generate a single `bundle.js`

However I noticed that I get the original source map references twice in the bundle, which doesn't seem to work.

Passing `--debug` doesn't seem to do the trick either.

I had a feeling this issue: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/325 is somewhat related, but I couldn't figure out how the issue was resolved.

Also https://github.com/substack/browser-pack was suggested, but again I don't fully understand how to use it, is it a replacement to browserify?

Bottom line, I would like to merge the 2 js files but "merge" the js to ts source maps using browserify. Is that possible?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/ben-ng/minifyify

Comment: Thanks @idbehold. Feel free to expand it to a full answer and collect the bounty, I haven't tested it but I rather someone get the bounty than waste it, and your comment sounds very promising (will try it today!)

Comment: @dystroy - how would I do that? I can't simply concatenate the files without taking care of the module / exports context, or am I missing something? Or do you mean to compile using `--out FILE`? it might be a bug in tsc, but it simply didn't work for me.

Comment: p.s. comment in HN with some suggestions: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7794545

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the [minifyify](https://github.com/ben-ng/minifyify) browserify plugin I believe you can use TypeScript with Browserify and retain the source maps. After compiling the TypeScript files you should be able to pass the "entry" file (the one that imports the other one via commonjs syntax) through browserify with the minifyify plugin.

```
var browserify = require('browserify'),
    bundler = new browserify();

bundler.add('entry.js');
bundler.plugin('minifyify', {map: 'bundle.js.map'});
bundler.bundle({debug: true}, function (err, src, map) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  fs.writeFileSync('bundle.js', src);
  fs.writeFileSync('bundle.js.map', map);
});
```

Comment: typscript sourcemaps does not load in firexfox-39. It works fine with firefox-42 nightly

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1166048

Comment: I am not sure how this is supposed to work. The bundle.js.map still contains mapping for the js files, not the ts files.

Answer (score 20):

[tsify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/tsify) is a browserify plugin that is better and replaces e.g. typescriptifier.

`npm install tsify browserify watchify`

You use tsify like this:

`browserify src/index.ts -p tsify --debug -o build/index.js`

Notice that this supports browserify `--debug` switch, no extra tricks required. So you can also use it with watchify like this:

`watchify src/index.ts -p tsify --debug -o build/index.js`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working solution:

```
var settings = {
  projectName : "test"
};    

gulp.task("bundle", function() {

  var mainTsFilePath = "src/main.ts";
  var outputFolder   = "bundle/src/";
  var outputFileName = settings.projectName + ".min.js";
  var pkg            = require("./package.json");

  var banner = [
    "/**",
    " * <%= pkg.name %> v.<%= pkg.version %> - <%= pkg.description %>",
    " * Copyright (c) 2015 <%= pkg.author %>",
    " * <%= pkg.license %>",
    " */", ""
  ].join("\n");

  var bundler = browserify({
    debug: true,
    standalone : settings.projectName
  });

  // TS compiler options are in tsconfig.json file
  return bundler.add(mainTsFilePath)
                .plugin(tsify)
                .bundle()
                .pipe(source(outputFileName))
                .pipe(buffer())
                .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
                .pipe(uglify())
                .pipe(header(banner, { pkg : pkg } ))
                .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(outputFolder));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created [example project](https://github.com/mxl/gulp-typescript-browserify-sourcemaps-example).

You can run it with `$(npm bin)/gulp build --env=dev` for development environment and source maps will be generated.

There is `gulpfile.js`:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    del = require('del'),
    typescript = require('gulp-typescript'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    browserify = require('browserify'),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    buffer = require('vinyl-buffer'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    inject = require('gulp-inject'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel'),
    argv = require('yargs').argv;

var devEnvironment = 'dev',
    prodEnvironment = 'prod',
    environment = argv.env || prodEnvironment,
    isDevelopment = environment === devEnvironment;

var projectPath = __dirname,
    srcDir = 'src',
    srcPath = path.join(projectPath, srcDir),
    buildDir = path.join('build', environment),
    buildPath = path.join(projectPath, buildDir),
    distDir = 'dist',
    distRelativePath = path.join(buildDir, distDir),
    distPath = path.join(buildPath, distDir);

var tsSrcPath = path.join(srcPath, 'typescript'),
    tsGlob = path.join(tsSrcPath, '**', '*.ts'),
    tsBuildPath = path.join(buildPath, 'tsc');

var indexHtmlName = 'index.html',
    indexJsName = 'index.js';

var distIndexJsPath = path.join(distPath, 'index.js'),
    distIndexHtmlPath = path.join(distPath, indexHtmlName);

var tsProject = typescript.createProject('tsconfig.json');

console.log('Environment: ' + environment);

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return del([buildPath]);
});

gulp.task('tsc', ['clean'], function () {
    var stream = gulp.src([tsGlob]);
    if (isDevelopment) {
        stream = stream
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init());
    }
    stream = stream
        .pipe(typescript(tsProject))
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }));
    if (isDevelopment) {
        stream = stream.pipe(sourcemaps.write({sourceRoot: tsSrcPath}));
    }
    return stream.pipe(gulp.dest(tsBuildPath));
});

gulp.task('bundle', ['tsc'], function () {
    var b = browserify({
        entries: path.join(tsBuildPath, indexJsName),
        debug: isDevelopment
    });

    var stream = b.bundle()
        .pipe(source(indexJsName))
        .pipe(buffer());
    if (!isDevelopment) {
        stream = stream.pipe(uglify());
    }
    return stream
        .on('error', gutil.log)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distPath));
});

gulp.task('build', ['bundle'], function() {
    return gulp.src(path.join(srcPath, indexHtmlName))
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src([distIndexJsPath], {read: false}), {ignorePath: distRelativePath, addRootSlash: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distPath));
});
```

You should pay attention to lines:

1. `stream = stream.pipe(sourcemaps.write('', {sourceRoot: tsSrcPath}));` - write inline source maps with `sourceRoot` pointing to your typescript sources path. Inline maps are written directly to `.js` files generated by `tsc` to `build/dev/tsc`.
2. `debug: isDevelopment` - in development environment make browserify generate his own source maps for resulting bundle `build/dev/dist/index.js` file so it will have source maps referencing `.js` files from `build/dev/tsc` which in turn have source maps referencing `.ts` files from `src/typescript`.

With this setup you will be able to see and debug `.ts` files in browser:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when trying to debug my Angular2 app running in Chrome in Visual Studio Code (Using Debugger for Chrome extension)

I use gulp as my task runner and my setup is as follows:
Typescript files -> tsc -> intermediate es5 js -> browserify (plus uglify in production build) -> compiled bundle

My directory structure is as follows:

```
|- src
    |- my .ts files here
    |- main.ts - my entry file
|- dist
    |- intermediate files go here
|- web
    |- app.js - final bundle
    |- app.js.map - final bundle map
|- gulpfile.js
```

`gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    tsc = require('gulp-typescript'),
    browserify = require('browserify'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');

gulp.task('tsc', [], () => {
            return gulp.src(['src/**/*.ts'])
                    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
                    .pipe(tsc({
                            "target": "es5",
                            "module": "commonjs",
                            "moduleResolution": "node",
                            "sourceMap": true,
                            "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
                            "experimentalDecorators": true,
                            "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
                            "noImplicitAny": true,
                            "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
                    }))
                    .pipe(sourcemaps.write(null, {
                            "sourceRoot": function(file) { 
                                    let parts = file.relative.split('\\');
                                    let root = Array(parts.length + 1).join('../') + 'src';
                                    return root;
                            }
                    }))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
    }); 
gulp.task('bundle', ['tsc'], () => {
    let b = browserify({
        entries: 'dist/main.js',
        debug: true,
    });

    return b.bundle()
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./', {
            "sourceRoot": "../",
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('web/'));
})

gulp.task('default', ['bundle']);
```

### Explanation/reasoning:

For some reason `browserify` doesn't read and parse .js.map files linked in .js file (via special comment at the end) but it does when the source map is embedded in js file. So, by passing `null` instead of path to `sourcemaps` it will embed it at the end of generated .js file.

Next issue I noticed was that `sourcemaps` doesn't automatically follow directory structure (add '../' to sourceRoot when it goes to next directory level), so I made a quick function to complement this. Keep in mind that it only works on Windows - on Linux you'd have to change split character.

```
function(file) { 
    let parts = file.relative.split('\\'); // put '/' here on Linux
    let root = Array(parts.length + 1).join('../') + 'src';
    return root;
}
```

Certainly there is a way to detect correct path separator, I'm debugging only on Windows thus it's not important for my purposes.

I hope it helps someone, cause I've spent whole Sunday morning tracking down this problem.

Comment: Does browserify consumes sourcemap when it is embedded in js file? I tried, with no result.