# browserify and files that allready have a sourcemap

Tags: javascript, browserify, source-maps

I have some JavaScript code that is compiled to commonJS modules from arbitrary compile-to-JS languages and I would like to debug the browserified code using sourcemaps.

So my files have a `//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map` already and I'd expect browserify to read that and transform them so I can debug with my original non-JS language.

Do I need another transform for this?

I tried it with browserify's debug flag, and then it does generate a sourcemap but it is for the intermediate JS files, and NOT the original non-JS files. I even see the original `//# sourceMappingURL` statements lingering in the bundle, and my browsers debugger doesn't like it a all.

Is this possible at all?

I see this: [Keep original typescript source maps after using browserify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453160/keep-original-typescript-source-maps-after-using-browserify) But it doesn't work.

Comment: Note: I've given up on browserify and moved to webpack because it solves problems with a lot less hassle.

Answer (score 3):

You can run [Sorcery](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/sorcery) on the output of broswerify. Sorcery will resolve a chain of sourcemaps until it gets to the original files. Sorcery emits a new sourcemap that has the original sources. This is not tied to any specific tool so it will work with webpack.

Installation: `npm install -g sorcery`

Usage: `sorcery -i outputOfBrowserify.js`
That command will overwrite the file and its source map in place.