# How to combine TypeScript code and JS libraries into one file with source maps?

Tags: javascript, typescript, uglifyjs, source-maps

I can successfully compile my TypeScript project into a single JS file with source maps using something like this:

```
tsc --sourcemap --out app.js app.ts
```

I can also successfully minify that output using UglifyJS, while keeping source maps intact:

```
uglifyjs app.js --source-map app.js.map --in-source-map app.js.map -o app.js
```

However, I would like to go slightly further. I want to combine my compiled TypeScript code (`app.js`) with a couple third-party JS libraries into a single minified file that maintains source maps pointing back to the original TypeScript (for my code) or JavaScript (for the third-party libraries).

I tried something like this, basically just adding a JS library file to the input to UglifyJS:

```
uglifyjs app.js lib/javascript-library.js --source-map app.js.map --in-source-map app.js.map -o app.js
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. It does successfully combine everything into one file, and the source maps for the TypeScript code seem to be preserved. But when I put an error in `lib/javascript-library.js`, the JS console in my browser (using source maps) says the error is in one of my TypeScript files, which is obviously wrong.

I am a TypeScript newb and I can't imagine I'm the first one to want to combine TS output with random JS libraries in a single minified file with source maps, but I can't find anyone talking about it. So maybe my approach is just completely wrong?

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/145

Comment: Maybe my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38679678/746347 will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 20):

Typescript compiler isn't so smart, to do this you need use more specific tools. Example: [gulpjs](http://gulpjs.com).

Requirements (if you know gulpjs skip this):

1. install [nodejs](http://nodejs.com)
2. run this: `npm install -g typescript gulp` to install gulp taskrunner
3. in project directory, run `npm init` and follow instruction to create package.json
4. run: `npm install gulp gulp-typescript gulp-concat gulp-uglify gulp-sourcemaps --save-dev` to install [ts compile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript), [concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat), [uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) e [generate sourcemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps) tools
5. create file with name gulpfile.js

Define 'compile' task in gulpfile.js :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('compile', function() {
     var tsResult = gulp.src('app.ts')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) // This means sourcemaps will be generated 
        .pipe(ts({
             sortOutput: true,
                       // ... 
         }));

      return tsResult
         .pipe(concat('lib/js-library.js')) // You can use other plugins that also support gulp-sourcemaps
         .pipe(uglify()) 
         .pipe(sourcemaps.write()) // Now the sourcemaps are added to the .js file 
         .pipe(gulp.dest('release/'));
});
```

And now, run `gulp compile` and see the magic!

Learn this packages and build your custom task compile.