# Preserve original sourcemap with Browserify

Tags: browserify, source-maps

Suppose I have a module whose source code is not ECMA 5 (e.g. it's Coffescript or Typescript or whatever) and is distributed in compiled form with a source map. How can I include this source map in a Browserify bundle?

For example imagine a project with a single dependency:

```
index.js
    node_modules
         typescript_module
              (main.ts)
              dist
                  main.js
                  main.js.map
```

The "main.js.map" is not consumed by browserify. That is, the browserify bundle source map maps to "main.js" instead of deferring to the original map which describes "main.ts"

For most transforms, there is a way to input source maps generated by the prior step, but is there a way to just preserve them on the original input files, when source maps already exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep original typescript source maps after using browserify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453160/keep-original-typescript-source-maps-after-using-browserify)

Comment: Saw that question - the answer is out of date at best, as the syntax is no longer supported by Browserify, but I'm not even trying to pass this through uglify/minify. Just plain old browserify with `{debug: true}` produces source maps with no reference to the original.

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be a bug/non-feauture of Browserify:

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/772

Answering my own question because it's very hard to track down any discussion of this issue with google and no mention of it in the Browserify docs.

Answer (score 3):

My setup is the following:

```
tsc --project tsconfig.script.json --outDir ~temp/ts
```

Compiles *src/script.ts* to *~temp/ts/script.js* and *~temp/ts/script.js.map*.

```
browserify ~temp/ts/script.js --debug | exorcist --root ../../ ~temp/bfy/script.js.map > ~temp/bfy/script.js
```

Compiles *~temp/ts/script.js* to *~temp/bfy/script.js* and *~temp/bfy/script.js.map*.

```
sorcery --input ~temp/bfy/script.js --output dist/script.js
```

Reads *~temp/bfy/script.js*; finds *~temp/bfy/script.js.map* + *~temp/ts/script.js.map*, and finally outputs *dist/script.js* and *dist/script.js.map*.

The *dist/script.js.map* file does reference the original *src/script.ts* file.

Requires [Browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify), [Exorcist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exorcist) and [Sorcery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sorcery) (and of course CoffeeScript or TypeScript or whatever).

Comment: Wow, thanks. I spent the whole day to make this work and you have provided the final piece.

A twist to my solution is that (1) in front of that pipeline I have Webpack and (2) at the end of the pipeline I'm building a Chrome Plugin.

Chrome plugins don't support external source map files (bug), so I had to adjust sorcery to generate an inline sourcemap.

Comment: But won't `~temp/bfy/script.js.map` be the JS map, not the original TS map?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a TypeScript library that you have control over (for example in a lerna monorepo), you can enable the following `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    // ...
  }
}
```

`browserify` should now use and transform the inlined source maps.

`browserify` will **not** read source maps that reference another file, it will only use *inlined source maps with inlined sources*. I have written about this in the referenced issue on GitHub [browserify/browserify#772](https://github.com/browserify/browserify/issues/772#issuecomment-476246117).

Alternatively, if you do not have control over the source of the TypeScript library, but you would still like to see the original source in DevTools, you can use the `sourceify` library someone mentioned in another answer. However, I had to patch it to work and I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/L8D/sourceify/pull/2). It hasn't been merged yet (at the time of writing this). If you wish to test it yourself, you can install it directly from my branch:

```sh
npm install https://github.com/jeremija/sourceify#sources-content
```

Make sure to use the global transform `-g [ sourceify ]`, because the default transform (`-t`) in Browserify does not modify files in `node_modules`.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [sourceify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sourceify).

Just install it:

```
npm i --save-dev sourceify
```

... and add it as a transform to `package.json`:

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "sourceify"
  ]
}
```

... and it Just Works.

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP, but unfortunately *sourceify* does not solve it. Note that I used `browserify temp/script.js -t [ sourceify ] --debug | exorcist --root ../ dist/script.js.map > dist/script.js` from the command line, to compile *temp/script.js* that came from `tsc --outDir temp`. That's unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var gulp        = require("gulp"),
    browserify  = require("browserify"),
    tsify       = require('tsify'),
    source      = require("vinyl-source-stream"),
    sourcemaps  = require("gulp-sourcemaps"),
    buffer      = require("vinyl-buffer"),
    uglify      = require("gulp-uglify"),
    header      = require("gulp-header");

var settings = {
  projectName : "test"
};    

gulp.task("bundle", function() {

  var mainTsFilePath = "src/main.ts";
  var outputFolder   = "bundle/src/";
  var outputFileName = settings.projectName + ".min.js";
  var pkg            = require("./package.json");

  var banner = [
    "/**",
    " * <%= pkg.name %> v.<%= pkg.version %> - <%= pkg.description %>",
    " * Copyright (c) 2015 <%= pkg.author %>",
    " * <%= pkg.license %>",
    " */", ""
  ].join("\n");

  var bundler = browserify({
    debug: true,
    standalone : settings.projectName
  });

  // TS compiler options are in tsconfig.json file
  return bundler.add(mainTsFilePath)
                .plugin(tsify)
                .bundle()
                .pipe(source(outputFileName))
                .pipe(buffer())
                .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
                .pipe(uglify())
                .pipe(header(banner, { pkg : pkg } ))
                .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(outputFolder));
});
```

Note: change the paths to match your project!