# VSCode breakpoint not working in typescript with sourcemap generated by gulp-sourcemaps

Tags: typescript, gulp, visual-studio-code, gulp-sourcemaps

I have a typescript file `users.ts` in a sub-directory `routes`.

The gulp code in `gulpfile.js`:

```
var tsProject = ts.createProject(tsConfigFile);
return tsProject.src()
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(ts(tsProject))
    .js
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {includeContent: false, sourceRoot: ''})) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
```

The sourcemap generated by `gulp-sourcemaps` does not work with VSCode :

```
{"version":3,"sources":["routes/users.ts"],"names":[], "mappings":"...","file":"routes/users.js","sourceRoot":""}
```

The sourcemap generated by `tsc` works fine in VSCode:

```
{"version":3,"file":"users.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["users.ts"],"names":[], "mappings":"..."}
```

and the VSCode breakpoint works fine with the sourcemap generated by `tsc`.

So how to config `gulp-typescript/gulp-sourcemaps` to generate the same sourcemap as `tsc`?

Comment: What is the `.js` call after `pipe(ts(tsProject))`?

Comment: see https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript#source-maps  , `.js` is called after `pipe(ts(tsProject))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the same problem as in [Gulp Typescript + Browserify; Bundled sourcemap points to transpiled JS rather than source TS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33903456/gulp-typescript-browserify-bundled-sourcemap-points-to-transpiled-js-rather-t) 
Add sourceRoot function to `sourcemaps.write(...)` 
Assuming your `.ts` files are in `src` folder of the project, `sourcemaps` pipe will look like:

```
.pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {
           sourceRoot: function(file){ return file.cwd + '/src'; }
      }))
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue as OP (also works fine with TSC generated sourcemaps), unfortunately this does not solve it.

Comment: Confirmed this works.  @pyrho Make sure that the '/src' part maps to root of your project relative to the root of your project.   You might need to use other values such as '' or '/src/server', etc.

Comment: Could you post the relevant bits of your gulpfile.js and your project layout ? Thanks !

Comment: Ok, I think I've found the issue. Using sourceRoot works fine. But for some reason gulp-typescript lowercases the filenames which somehow break VSCode's file mapping, see [this gulp-typescript issue](https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript/issues/255). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct, however it took me some time to realize why this worked & how to adjust the answer for my particular environment (in my case I needed to drop the `/src` suffix).

If you inspect the generated source maps (this only works when outputting to map files, e.g. `sourcemaps.write('.')`) you should see two fields in the json object: `sources` and `sourceRoot`, there are two things you need to be sure of:

1. `sourceRoot` should be an absolute path.
2. Each path in `sources` should combine with `sourceRoot` to form the absolute path to your source file.

If #1 isn't true the path will work in some cases and not in others (some tools resolve relative paths relative to source map file, others based on your workspace root, cwd, or some other path).

If #2 isn't true your tools will be looking in the wrong place for the source files.

One other hint: Remember that changing your gulpfile doesn't trigger a rerun of watch mode or clear any file caches, since your source file didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Sourcemap paths will be correct on the machine where you build them with v-andrew's method.  However, if you want to compile the sourcemaps once to work on multiple machines, use relative filepaths:

```
var path = require('path');

...

.pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {
  includeContent: false,
  sourceRoot: function(file) {
    var fullPath = path.join(file.cwd, file.path);
    return path.relative(fullPath, file.base);
  },
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using gulp-sourcemaps 2.6.1 on Windows, and @Westy92's solution doesn't work (anymore?), because file.path returns the absolute file path (including file name):

```
var path = require('path');

...

.pipe(sourcemaps.write({
  includeContent: false,
  sourceRoot: function(file) {
    return path.relative(path.dirname(file.path), file.base);
  },
}))
```